# Conditionally use of f:setPropertyActionListener

Tags: jsf, primefaces, conditional-rendering, setpropertyactionlistener

Is it possible to conditionally use the f:setPropertyActionListener inside a commandButton?

```
<p:commandButton value="button" process="@this" update=":someForm" action="#{someMB.someAction}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{someMB.someAttr}" value="#{someValue}" disabled="#{someCondition}"/> 
</p:commandButton>
```

like the disabled attr in the f:setPropertyActionListener.

What I usually do is make 2 different buttons with rendered properties.

Comment: Wouldn't be better if you use a hidden field whose value is set when clicking on your button?

Comment: Answer depends on what exactly `#{someCondition}` is.

Comment: a boolean condition... I need to set a property (a boolean flag), if a bean value is X or Y... like, if (myValue="A"), setPropetyAction target=myValue value=true... otherwise keep the current myValue value.

Comment: I also, just thought of using a ternary operator on value field, is this possible on EL?

Comment: Try setting target equal to (myValue==A) instead of just A. i.e value=(myvalue=='A')

Comment: I solved my problem by doing the rules, late on the action, works, but, not what I wanted... I still dont know what is the best practice for this kind of problem.

Comment: Again, answer depends on what **exactly** `someCondition` is. For example, if it were a variable which is available during view build time, then you could just wrap it in a `<c:if>`.